# Uso de "Y" en lugar de "que" en Mexico para cláusulas subordinadas

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, méxico, dialectos

Muchas veces en México he oído que se dice algo así:

> "Ójala **y** llueva mañana."

Por supuesto en español formal debería ser:

> "Ójala **que** llueva mañana."

Mi pregunta es la siguiente.  ¿Cómo trata la Academia Mexicana de la lengua refiriéndose a este aparente arcaísmo (parece que viene del uso medieval del castellano)?  ¿Es considerado solamente incorrecto en términos gramáticales o es considerado un uso regional del dialecto mexicano?

Como pregunta adicional, ¿hay otros dialectos del castellano en otros países donde se usa esto también?

Comment: Hay una errata en el título, creo que debería poner "claúsulas" en lugar de "clásulas". Como solo es un caracter, no puedo sugerirlo como edición.

Comment: Gracias @RubioRic, hice el cambio.  Debería ser "cláusulas."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De la Academia Mexicana de la Lengua (Méjico no es una monarquía, por lo que no puede ser real) en sí, no tengo idea, pero coeditó el Diccionario de Americanismos, y este dice lo siguiente:

> **y.**
>   **I.    1.**    conj. *Mx, Ch, Py*. Se usa para enfatizar en construcciones que expresan deseo o mandato.

Es decir, habrá una diferencia entre decir *ojalá que…* y *ojalá y…*, siendo el segundo más enfático que el primero.  Según este diccionario, también se emplea en Chile y el Paraguay. [Según HydraExiled](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27681/4182), también se usa en Puerto Rico.

Comment: Gracias Guifa, Yo pensaba que todas las Academias de la lengua se llamaron "reales."  Bueno, pero esto me contesta la pregunta si es considerado incorrecto u otra forma. Gracias.

Comment: @Karlomanio no pertenece al español estándar, pero que se reconozca como algo de uso muy común (y con restricciones particulares), eso sin duda.  No lo usaría en un documento formal o con fines panhispánicos, pero si estuviera en esos sitios, tampoco descartaría usarlo en conversaciones o documentos informales.

Comment: @guifa Soy chileno y jamás escuché una expresión semejante a la de la pregunta, con la **y**, pero creo haberla escuchado de argentinos.

Answer (score 4):

Contestando a tu segunda pregunta, de seguro hay otros países que usan las dos formas, siendo la segunda mas formal en gramática.

"Ojala y todos estén bien" -
"Ojala que todos estén bien"

Ambas se usan en Puerto Rico, y seguro que en otros países también lo utilizan.